# Identifying errors in quadratic equations

Tags: python, numerical-methods, quadratic

Suppose you write a Python program to calculate the real roots of ax<sup>2</sup> + bx + c = 0, where the coefficients a, b and c are given, real numbers. The traditional formulas for the two solutions are

```
x1 = (-b - sqrt(b*b-4*a*c)) / 2a, 
x2 = (-b + sqrt(b*b-4*a*c)) / 2a.
```

I need to identify situations (values ​​of the coefficients) where the formulas do not make sense or lead to large rounding errors, and propose alternative formulas that can be used in these cases in order to avoid a problem.

What do I need to do?

Comment: I fixed the equations again; they were still wrong.

Comment: You may want to start your research here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Solving_the_quadratic_equation

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The only time when there may be issues is when `a` is equal to (or very close to) zero.  In such cases, the equation becomes linear.

Comment: This is not a python question, but one about error propagation in calculations. Hint: subtracting two big numbers is usually bad. Please study the relevant theory a bit more before asking us to do your homework.

Answer (score 2):

There are two situations where problems arise. The first is when the term inside the square root (the "Discriminant") goes negative, i.e.

```
if(b*b - 4*a*c < 0 ):
  # do something. This doesn't have real roots
```

The second is more subtle. When you subtract two large numbers that are almost the same size, there is a possibility of rounding error. This will happen for the smaller root when `4*a*c << b*b`. You could do a series expansion:

```
b - sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c)
= b * ( 1 - sqrt(1 - 4 * a * c / (b * b)))
~ b * ( 1 - 1 + 2 * a * c / (b * b))        # when 4*a*c << b*b
```

This term becomes

```
2 * a * c / b
```

So the final root would be

```
x1 = - c / b
```

Which is an interesting result. Of course the other root is still

```
x2 = (b + sqrt( b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)
```

Not much error propagation there - although you could say that it will tend to

```
x2 = - b / a
```

when c becomes very small.

All this has nothing to do with Python - it is basic math. And I may have made errors - go ahead and see if you can find them.

For more help you might want to look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Floating-point_implementation

Which provides a treatment of this issue in terms of numerical stability. You will find, among others, that the equations I (re)derived above are called "Vieta's formula".